# Flask web app deployment in Google Cloud App Engine gives favicon.ico error

Tags: flask, google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine, google-cloud-run

I created a simple app to test Google Cloud App Engine deployments.
The app deploys successfully to google cloud but the site just says: "Service Unavailable" and shows the following error: 503 (Service Unavailable).

It works fine locally.

requirements.txt

```
Flask==2.1.2
```

app.yml

```
runtime: python39
entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT app:app

instance_class: F2

env_variables:
  FLASK_ENV: "production"
```

File structure:
[file structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/187GM.png)

This is what I did to try to solve it but, not working in deployment.

app.py

```
from flask import Flask, send_from_directory
import os

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello():
    return 'Hello, World!'

@app.route('/favicon.ico')
def favicon():
    return send_from_directory(os.path.join(app.root_path, 'static'), 'favicon.ico', mimetype='image/vnd.microsoft.icon')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, port=8080)
```

I also tried using FastAPI and Cloud Run deployments but both show the same error. What am I missing?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Does it work locally?

Comment: @dimitry I deleted the image of the error as you asked. Sorry about that

Comment: @guillaume yes, it works locally. I just added that to the post, thanks for asking.

Answer (score 1):

For deploying to Google App Engine

1. Remove the route handler for `favicon.ico` from your python code.
2. Put your favicon in the root of your App folder.
3. Then update your `app.yaml` file and add the following as one of your handlers

   ```
   handlers:
   - url: /favicon\.ico
     static_files: favicon.ico
     upload: favicon\.ico
   ```

**Note:**

a) If you wish to keep your favicon in your current location (within static) then change `static_files` to `static/favicon.ico`

b) I know you're testing but using F2 instance will be expensive if someone hits your url or you forget to shut it down (while you're still testing).

Comment: thank you for your great explanations. The issue is half-solved. Error for favicon.ico is gone but, the deployment is still not working. The server responds 503 Service unavailable.
I checked the log files in the App Engine and based on DuetAI support chat this summarizes the log entry:
-The request failed because the instance failed the readiness check.
-This request caused a new process to be started for your application, and thus caused your application code to be loaded for the first time. This request may thus take longer and use more CPU than a typical request.

Comment: @ShakeSystems Do you still have the same basic 'hello world' application or did you add more code? Your hello world application shouldn't give that error. Are you using App Engine Standard or is this Flex?

Comment: thank you for replying back. I did not added more code, just hello world. I am using App Engine Standard.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this I added the gunicorn into the requirements.txt in order for  the entrypoint to be able to work when deploying to google.

Fixed requirements.txt:

```
Flask==3.0.0
gunicorn==20.1.0
```

Also, don't forget to install this into your gcloud CLI:

> gcloud components install app-engine-python